# Possible to estimate distribution around mean given #samples, mean, highest and lowest?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, mean, median

For a project for which there are multiple bidders, the following is known:

- Number of bidders: 24
- Mean bid: 104
- Highest bid: 356
- Lowest bid: 20

Given the above, is it possible (however roughly) to estimate (i) the number of bids above and below the mean and (ii) the median?

Comment: Not necessarily, if the other 22 values can be anything within that range.

Comment: by *not necessarily*, you mean not likely, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is not enough information in the descriptive statistics you have provided to estimate 1) number of bids above and below mean and 2) median.

For 1), you need information regarding the overall shape of the distribution. At the very least you'd want information regarding whether the distribution is symmetrical around the mean or not.  This information could be expressed as a Bernoulli trial: $p = Pr(x > \bar x )$.  Obviously, if you knew $p$, you could multiply it by the total number of bids to estimate the number of bids above the mean, and the subtract from the total number of bids for the reverse.

Are $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ informative regarding $p$?  Not *sufficiently* informative, unfortunately. (EDIT: they do provide a *sliver* of information that allow you to rule the most extreme estimates for 1). But in most cases, this sliver of information is not very useful.)

For 2), you also need information regarding the overall shape of the distribution.  For example, it would help to know the number of modes and their positions, and some information about the skew of the distribution.

---

If you have out-of-band information (e.g. from simulations) regarding the shape or type of distribution (e.g. Beta distribution) then you can combine this prior information with these descriptive statistics to estimate 1) and 2).

Comment: It's not true that there's *no* information available here. For example, we know that the number of bids below the mean is greater than 1; if the other 22 observations were each $104 + \varepsilon$, the mean would be $\frac{22}{24}(104 + \varepsilon) + \frac{20}{24} + \frac{356}{24} = 111 + \frac{11}{12}\varepsilon$. It is true that without some assumptions on the distribution we can't say much about the probabilities other than where they must be 0.

Comment: @Dougal - You are correct.  MIN and MAX provide a *sliver* of information, but as you say that information isn't very useful most of the time.

Comment: @MrMeritology I see, thanks. I would have thought that given that the highest bid is a lot higher than than the mean than the lowest was lower than the mean, that we might be able to infer that the majority of the bids were above it. But like you say, if we don't have any information to make this inference, so be it.